# primary key INT for emoji

Tags: mysql, primary-key, emoji

I am writing a MySQL table to store data about every single emoji:

```
CREATE TABLE `emoji` (
    `emoji_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `html` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`emoji_id`)
);
```

An example insertion might be:

```
INSERT INTO `emoji` VALUES (12345, 'grinning face', '&#x1F600;');
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO `emoji` VALUES (67890, 'woman walking', '&#x1F6B6;&#x200D;&#x2640;&#xFE0F;');
```

However, instead of my own proprietary ID number `12345` or `567890`, I would like to use a universal decimal number that is already assigned to each emoji.

Does such an ID number exist?

I thought about simply converting the hexadecimal representation to decimal to use as the `emoji_id` primary key, however this does not work because some emoji (such as my second example) are represented by a sequence of hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: You shouldn't use value as a source for primary key. Imagine the scenario, when all emoji codes are changed, and you have messed up your entire table because of that.

Comment: if you lookup https://emojipedia.org/grinning-face/ for example, you will see the unicode value for that emoji: **U+1F600** which you could use, but as @pavjel states, any standard CAN change...

Comment: If the standard changes, then I simply update the table, no big deal. I'm asking if a current standard decimal ID number exists. Thanks.

Comment: Now imagine standard changes once a week. You still would like to perform such actions that frequently? I don't think so. It's not about the effort needed to accomplish it, it's about right approach.

Comment: If a standard changes once a week, then it's not a standard. Furthermore if you can offer an alternative "right" approach, I'd be curious to hear what yours is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing I have found is Unicode.org's [complete list of emoji](https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html). The first column is a unique decimal number for each emoji. For example, the decimal ID number of "house" is 735, and the decimal ID number of "woman walking" is 343.